# Covering map of a Torus

Tags: algebraic-topology, covering-spaces

How would I draw (describe) a covering map given by

1. $T^{2}\#T^{2}\#T^{2}\#T^{2}\#T^{2}\#T^{2}\ \rightarrow T^{2}\#T^{2}$
2. $T^{2}\#T^{2}\#T^{2}\#T^{2}\rightarrow T^{2}\#T^{2}$

and what would be the degree of this covering? I know the surfaces are orientable of genus $g$ and can be constructed from a polygon with $4g$ sides, and they become a union of $2g$ circles in the surface, so I guess that union would be a covering map and its degree would be the $g$.

Could somebody help with it?
Thanks

Comment: Think of $T^2\# T^2$ as a donut with a handle. Then these covers are gotten by unwinding the central donut. The single handle becomes $k$ handles in a $k$-sheeted cover.

Comment: Unwinding a donut? Man, that's trippy...

Comment: Do you mean like half a donut with a handle? Can I unwind the donut too?

Comment: @IgorRivin: maybe I'll start a band with that name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Imagine a closed chain of tori (that is, torus $i$ is connected-summed to tori $i+1$ and $i-1$ mod $2k.$) That is a (cyclic) $k$-fold cover of a double torus (surface of genus $2.$).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Is it right what Gottfried draw? what would be the degree for the first map for example?, thanks again

Answer (score 1):

The first figure correspond to a 7 degree cover of the double torus, and the second one to a 4 degree cover!

[image]